# Teacher badge for question with negative score?

Tags: support, badges

What does this badge mean?

A recently received badge on my part ("Teacher") requires "Answer a question with score of 1 or more". However, the question score is negative, and I am puzzled.

The way I see it, I have 3 possible ways of reading this new badge:

1. Answer a question whose score is or becomes 1 or more.
2. Answer a question, after which said answer is both accepted and upvoted.
3. I get badge, I Smert! YAY!!

Since I don't especially care about the quantity (or my current lack thereof) of badges (currently auditioning for "Treasure of the Stack Overflow", call back times may be left in comments), I decided to try to understand. Is the badge description ambiguous, the badge criteria non-zero instead of positive, or are my reading abilities questionable at best, only proving that I don't deserve the badge?

Comment: The wording is ambiguous.  It means that your _answer has a positive score_, not the question.  Reading #2 is correct.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The answer doesn't need to be accepted.

Comment: Sorry good catch @Servy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading #2 is (almost) correct, your *answer* needs to have a score of 1 or more, but it *doesn't* need to accepted. Meta SE has a [full list of badges and their descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) - this is what it says about the Teacher badge:

> #### Teacher
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Receive a score of one on an answer

The wording is ambiguous indeed - if you have a better proposal, you can post it (at Meta SE) as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).